# Cannot shutdown my Sony Vaio

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, hibernate, vaio

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 (dual boot with Windows 7) on my sony Vaio.
After the fresh install everything was working fine. then

1. I was informed that new driver were available for my ATI video card (I first tried to install the post-release one but it was not possible so I selected the one tested by canonical)
2. After that I noticed a bug where my laptop was rebooting instead of resuming from hibernate (i.e if I was closing the lid .. the laptop was hibernating but if I was opening the lid the laptop was shutting down)
3. It was a bug I already experienced in 11.10 and I fixed it by amending the grub file from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"` ... the fix sorted out that issue but introduced a new issue .. now when I shutdown my laptop it hangs on the splash screen (Ubuntu logo with the 4 dots) and nothing happens.
4. I tried to use the following fix `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"` but it is not working.

Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.

PS: after 5 years using Ubuntu this is the first time I am not able to find the solution within a week

Comment: The fglrx driver will cause our computer to hang while shutting down.  I had reported the bug here. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/995184

Answer (score 1):

Solved by doing the following:

I've rolled back the grub file as it was originally (only quiet splash option), then:

```
update-grub
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
sudo aticonfig --initial
update-grub
```

Looks like that installing ati driver from the ubuntu driver update GUI is not a smooth process.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Thinkpad t500. Same problem here, after installing fglrx-updates shutdown hangs forever

Comment: reported http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/995184

Comment: This is the correct answer! I just posted it again with a picture of my bios setting.

Answer (score 1):

Mybe wrong to post it as an answer but i wanted to add an image:

with my Thinkpad T 500 shutdown hangs after `aptitude install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates`.

I needed to change BIOS settings like this:

[image]

and then i ran

```
sudo update-grub
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
sudo aticonfig --initial
sudo update-grub
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Did your Ubuntu splash screen shows up ugly? (I mean low- res)

Comment: First yes, but i think this is another problem, which i fixed by "cp /usr/share/grub/*.pf2 /boot/grub && update-grub" see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802

Comment: Thanks for the bug link!  And I thought I was the only person in the ubuntu community that got the low -res boot screen after install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-grub` fixed my 12.04 shutdown problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it may help:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off apm power_off=1 quiet splash"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and restart.

This fixed the problem on my notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... do you know where I can find the meaning of all the options we can pass to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ? Apart from quiet splash I have no idea of what the other options mean ...  Thank you

Comment: @kaizer You might want to post a new question asking if there is an online source that lists and explains all possible Linux kernel boot options. I'm not sure if there's a good current source for this, but if so, it would be quite valuable.