# Toshiba Satellite A660 can't shutdown

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

My Ubuntu 12.04 can't shutdown correctly. It doesn't happen all the time but it does happen quite frequently. Is there any way to find out what modules (or anything) stops the shutdown process?

I tried the method posted here:
[Cannot shutdown my Sony Vaio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140168/cannot-shutdown-my-sony-vaio-on-ubuntu-12-04)
But it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire up a terminal and locate the boot logs. They are usually (as well as other logs) in `/var/log` directory. An `ls | grep boot` in that directory in my machine brings up two files. One called `boot` which doesn't have anything in it and another called `boot.log` which seems to include the messages during the last boot attempt.

Now, if you would like to see the messages your kernel produces during boot time, you will have to fire up an editor and edit `/etc/default/grub` in which you shoudl change a line that reads `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` to `false`

Comment: My problem is can't shut down not can't boot up, why I need to see the messages for boot time?