# Can't shutdown Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, tty

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04**. I've been away for a few weeks, and after I've logged in, I've updated my system to the latest updates, as normal.

However, now I can't shut down any more. Every time I try, I end up with the Ubuntu screen frozen. I can only do a hard shut-down/restart. I've looked into the logs, but I am not really sure which one to check. I've run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but nothing comes up.

It would be nice to see the commands he is running while trying to shut down. I'm pretty sure it's something related to X11, but I can't find it.

Any hints? Maybe which log to check or how to reboot seeing the command line?

cheers.

Edit: I've checked **/var/log/kern.log** and I've found the following entry at the shut down time:

```
Sep 29 21:34:01 xxx kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Sep 29 21:38:39 xxx kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

This was clearly the time of a reboot try. From what I've read just now, the first message is clearly the shut-down and second message is the boot. So, no proof of hard-reset. ?! puzzled...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/140168/cannot-shutdown-my-sony-vaio

Comment: Try doing a `sudo shutdown now`

Comment: How did you try to shutdown your system?

Comment: Well, normal shut down via the graphical interface. Then I've tried a CTRL-ALT-F1: sudo reboot, but it got stuck again. I've just tried now the suggestions from the possible duplicate, see what comes... I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Well it didn't work. I even tried sudo shutdown -v now, and still no meta-info is shown, I still see the Ubuntu splash logo for shutting down, and then freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Or at least I hope I have :) One successful reboot so far, fingers crossed :)

I had a hunch that the issue was with the video driver, namely with the fact that some **fglrx*** package might have been updated. So, I followed my [own tutorial](https://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/category/troubleshooting/video-troubleshooting/) regarding ATI video-cards re-installation (in the past I had a lot of issue with my ATI drivers, so I wrote that post to help me). I reverted to the **mesa** drivers, and now the reboot seems to work:

```
$sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
$sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bck
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
$sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
$sudo reboot
```

For now I'll stick to said drivers and won't install the official ATI one. Anyway, the official driver for my card is a legacy one, last updated in January 2013 (quite old I would say)